# Powershell Script to Merge Multiple CSV with Some Shared Headers

Tags: excel, powershell, csv, merge

I have limited access to programming tools due to company policy.

I am using PowerShell to convert several Excel files contained in a folder to convert these files into CSVs and then merge those CSVs together.

So far I have created my script so that it converts all the excel files and create another part which combines those CSVs and outputs it into 1 CSV

**My Issue:**

The output CSV does not group the similar headers together and in essence the output CSV I created is useless.

I have 8 CSV's with the following headers

**INPUT:** (CSVs)

1. Grantee, Role, Admin, Delegator, Default, Common
2. Grantee, Role, Admin, Delegator, Default, Common
3. Grantee, Role, Admin, Delegator, Default, Common
4. Grantee, Role, Admin, Delegator, Default, Common
5. Grantee, Role, Admin, Default
6. Grantee, Role, Admin, Default
7. Grantee, Role, Admin, Default
8. Grantee, Role, Admin, Default

**OUTPUT:**

1 CSV with the following Headers:

`Grantee, Role, Admin, Delegator, Default, Common`

Duplicates are okay to have in the output file,
I don't know how to handle null values for the the 4 csvs that dont have "Delegator" and "Common" headers.

This is what I have so far:

```
foreach($file in (Get-ChildItem "C:\Users\ZZZZZZ\Desktop\PROJECT"))
{
    $newname = $file.FullName -replace '\.xls$', '.csv'
    $ExcelWB = new-object -comobject excel.application
    $Workbook = $ExcelWB.Workbooks.Open($file.FullName)
    $Workbook.SaveAS($newname,6)
    $Workbook.Close($false)
    $ExcelWB.quit()
}

#combines all csv 
#combines them but does not line up the shared headers and also inserts the headers of the new csv into the sheet, would like to only have 1 header in the output

$files = Get-ChildItem C:\Users\ZZZZZZ\Desktop\Project\*.csv 
Get-Content $files | Set-Content C:\Users\ZZZZZZ\Desktop\Project\MERGED.csv
```

I really appreciate any help anyone can give me, had to do a lot of research to get to this point "how to install powershell","how to 'write' scripts" and this is my first time using PowerShell.

Answer (score 0):

Use the `Import-Csv` and `Export-Csv` cmdlets:

```
Get-ChildItem C:\Users\ZZZZZZ\Desktop\Project\*.csv |ForEach-Object {
  Import-Csv $_.FullName
} |Select-Object Grantee,Role,Admin,Delegator,Default,Common |Export-Csv C:\Users\ZZZZZZ\Desktop\Project\MERGED.csv -NoTypeInformation
```

For the files that don't have the `Delegator` and `Common` headers, the values will just be empty in the merged CSV file

Comment: Thanks for the help Mathias, I think we are headed in the right direction however it seems to create a csv that never ends. The process keeps running until I terminate it.